# Update failure in python google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have successfully installed google app engine SDK for python in ubuntu-15.04. Its working fine for localhost. There is error arise for given command.

```
$ dev_appserver.py .
INFO     2015-07-21 06:18:19,221 api_server.py:205] Starting API server at: http://localhost:55916
INFO     2015-07-21 06:18:19,224 dispatcher.py:197] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:8080
INFO     2015-07-21 06:18:19,236 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:8000
INFO     2015-07-21 06:19:49,695 module.py:809] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 13
```

Everything is working fine till now.

When i want to update it, it give an error

```
$ appcfg.py update .
Usage: appcfg.py [options] update <directory> | [file, ...]

appcfg.py: error: Expected -A app_id when application property in file app.yaml is not set
```

what does it mean?can someone help me to fix this error?If there is problem of app id then how will i get the app id?
Thanks
.

Comment: Go to https://console.developers.google.com/project & register a new project. Once you have it, the very first line of your `app.yaml` should be `application: <the_new_app_id_you_just_registered>`

Answer (score 3):

The last line of the second dump is telling you that the 'application property' in the config file app.yaml is not set. Add a line in the beginning like this:

```
application: <name>
```

where `<name>` is replaced with your application name.
You can also update by using appcfg with the -A tag:

```
appcfg.py -A <name> update <directory>
```

, again replacing `<name>` and `<directory>` with the desired application name and the project directory where the app.yaml file exists.